# How do use the soup.find, soup.find_all

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is my code and the output

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
res = requests.get("https://www.jobberman.com/jobs")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
job = soup.find("div", class_ = "relative inline-flex flex-col w-full text-sm font-normal pt-2")
company_name = job.find('a[href*="jobs"]')
print(company_name)
```

output is none

```
None
```

But when i use the select method, i got the desired result but cant use .text on it

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.jobberman.com/jobs")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
job = soup.find("div", class_ = "relative inline-flex flex-col w-full text-sm font-normal pt-2")
company_name = job.select('a[href*="jobs"]').text
print(company_name)
```

output

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: Maybe you should study [searching-the-tree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) - plenty of examples in it. You cannot use the same "wildcards" for `.find()` as for `.select()` - they work differently. You could use regex with find - if you know how that works. It is all described in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Change your selection strategy - Cause main issue here is, that not all company names are linked:

```
job.find('div',{'class':'search-result__job-meta'}).text.strip()
```

or

```
job.select_one('.search-result__job-meta').text.strip()
```

##### Example

Also store your information in a structured way for post processing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.jobberman.com/jobs")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
data = []
for job in soup.select('div:has(>.search-result__body)'):
    data.append({
        'job':job.h3.text,
        'company':job.select_one('.search-result__job-meta').text.strip()
    })
data
```

###### Output

```
[{'job': 'Restaurant Manager', 'company': 'Balkaan Employments service'},
 {'job': 'Executive Assistant', 'company': 'Nolla Fresh & Frozen ltd'},
 {'job': 'Portfolio Manager/Instructor 1', 'company': 'Fun Science World'},
 {'job': 'Microbiologist', 'company': "NEIMETH INT'L PHARMACEUTICALS PLC"},
 {'job': 'Data Entry Officer', 'company': 'Nkoyo Pharmaceuticals Ltd.'},
 {'job': 'Chemical Analyst', 'company': "NEIMETH INT'L PHARMACEUTICALS PLC"},
 {'job': 'Senior Front-End Engineer', 'company': 'Salvo Agency'},...]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problems with your search strategy has been covered by comments and answers posted earlier. I am offering a solution for your problem which involves the use of regex library, along with the find_all() function call:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    
    res = requests.get("https://www.jobberman.com/jobs")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    company_name = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile("/jobs\?"), rel="nofollow")
    for i in range(len(company_name)):
        print(company_name[i].text)
```

Output:

```
GRATIAS DEI NIGERIA LIMITED

Balkaan Employments service

Fun Science World

NEIMETH INT'L PHARMACEUTICALS PLC

Nkoyo Pharmaceuticals Ltd.

...
```